# The behavior of /* comment when printing to stdout in C++

Tags: c++, comments, stdout

my question comes from the following 2 simple line of C++ code:

```
cout<<"/*";
cout<<"*/";
```

In my opinion, the comment delimiters `/* */` eat the characters `";` and `cout<<"` which is inside of them. So the two lines must be equal to:

```
cout<<"";
```

Surprisingly, when I compile and test the code, the program prints:

```
/**/
```

It is likely the program recognize comment delimiter as normal characters. How could that be? The code was compiled in gcc-c++-4.7.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/misc/nestcomment.html).

> The character sequences /* and */ are not special within double-quoted
>   strings, and do not therefore introduce comments, because a program
>   (particularly one which is generating C code as output) might want to
>   print them. (It is hard to imagine why anyone would want or need to
>   place a comment inside a quoted string. It is easy to imagine a
>   program needing to print "/*".)

Comment: Thanks. It seems C FAQ or standard is helpful for understanding C++ grammar. Previously I think /* and */ eat everything inside in anywhere because C++ Primer 5th Edition (P9) said: `These comments ca include anything that is not a */, including newlines. The compiler treats everything that falls between the /* and */ as part of the comment.` Did they ignore the case that `/**/` are inside of `""`?

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that this is not only the case in C/C++, but in all programming languages I have met so far.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard tells us how to run the parser, and it turns out that (for various reasons) when you begin parsing a string literal, you don't stop until you reach the end double-quote, even if there's a comment character in the middle. Try some of these:

```
cout<<"// this won't give an error";

cout<<"Does it print /* this here */?";
```

Comment: Yes it prints `// this won't give an error` and `Does it print /* this here */?`. In the case you explained is more reasonable to phrase as string, I will keep this in my mind. Thanks.